# Problem with discord.py background task looping

Tags: python, discord.py

I've been trying to fix this error for ages now. So basically I'm trying to loop task with now 3 different ways and this is the closest I've gotten but can't figure out why this error occurs

> Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                 File "/home/jupe/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 607, in _load_from_module_spec                                                                               spec.loader.exec_module(lib)                                                                   File "", line 779, in exec_module                          File "", line 916, in get_code                             File "", line 846, in source_to_code                       File "", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed                     File "/home/jupe/bot/modules/task.py", line 25                                                     def setup(bot):                                                                                  ^                                                                                            SyntaxError: invalid syntax                                                                                                                                                                       The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:                                                                                                                              Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                 File "main.py", line 12, in                                                                bot.load_extension(f'modules.{filename[:-3]}')                                                 File "/home/jupe/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 664, in load_extension                                                                                       self._load_from_module_spec(spec, name)                                                        File "/home/jupe/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 610, in _load_from_module_spec                                                                               raise errors.ExtensionFailed(key, e) from e                                                  discord.ext.commands.errors.ExtensionFailed: Extension 'modules.task' raised an error: SyntaxError: invalid syntax (task.py, line 25)

this error comes in this code which should be perfectly working

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
import os

class CogBackground(commands.Cog):
    
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
    
    async def scan(path):
        for file in os.listdir(path):
            x=os.stat(file)
            Result=(time.time()-x.st_mtime) 
            print("The age of the given file is: ",Result)

    async def task(self, ctx):
        self.scan("imgs/")
        await asyncio.sleep(15)

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self, ctx):
        self.bot.loop.create_task(self.task(ctx)

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(CogBackground(bot))
```

Comment: You didn't close your bracket in the on_ready function. Also, I can't find anything about a "create_task" function anywhere in the docs, so I don't think it should be perfectly working.
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search.html?q=create_task

Comment: it still somehow worked before I moved it into Cog but I'll close the bracket thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in the first line of code of the `on_ready` event, also the `scan` function is a coroutine so you have to await it.

```py
await self.scan('./imgs')
```

A better alternative to that is the use of the built-in `discord.ext.tasks` extension, it's simply a better alternative

```py
from discord.ext import tasks

# In the cog 
@tasks.loop(seconds=15.0)
async def task(self):
    await self.scan('./imgs')

@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_ready(self):
    self.task.start()
```